# Is it possible to browse all directories in file system using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, directory, sql-injection

I'm currently studying SQL injection, and I wonder if it's possible to display all the directories using an SQL injection in MySQL? I mean, I know, that there's a load_file() function that allows to display a file, but what about directories (their contents)? Does it takes to upload some kind of shell or there's a better solution to display all the contents?

Comment: Simple answer is no, The is a database after all. btw what is sqli?  You can do that in python or php c# and so on

Comment: @nbk Sqli is for sql injection

Comment: I edited the question to spell out "SQL injection" where you wrote "sqli". Please don't use a non-standard abbreviation without explaining what you mean by it.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [LOAD_FILE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) will not read directories. It only reads regular files.

Here's a link to the specific line of code that checks if the file you tried to open is a regular file, and if it isn't, return an error.
https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/item_strfunc.cc#L3498

```
  if (!MY_S_ISREG(stat_info.st_mode)) {
    my_error(ER_TEXTFILE_NOT_READABLE, MYF(0), file_name->c_ptr());
    mysql_file_close(file, MYF(0));
    DBUG_ASSERT(maybe_null);
    return error_str();
  }
```

We can also demonstrate. I created a file "/tmp/world" and put the word "hello" into it.

I can read the file:

```
 MySQL  localhost:33060+ ssl  SQL > select load_file('/tmp/world');
+-------------------------+
| load_file('/tmp/world') |
+-------------------------+
| hello
                  |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.0007 sec)
```

But I can't read the directory:

```
 MySQL  localhost:33060+ ssl  SQL > select load_file('/tmp');
ERROR: 1085: The file '/tmp' must be in the database directory or be readable by all
```

This error isn't clear about the real reason it can't read the file. It just returns a general error corresponding to the code constant `ER_TEXTFILE_NOT_READABLE`.